# How to use custom Adapter after parsing data from server

Tags: android, listview, android-studio

**ANSWERED BY ME**

I am confused where to put and how to use my custom adapter.
My Parser.class has its own Adapter and my MainActivity is passing 3 parameters to the Parser.class (context, url, listview).

(Making my problem simple)

After creating a custom layout, custom adapter, and instantiating my custom adapter, I don't know what to do.

I tried instantiating my custom adapter in my MainActivity then creating `MainActivity m = new MainActivity();` in my Parser.class and just use the textviews of my custom listview like `m.name_tv.setText(name);` and `m.price_tv.setText(price)` then changing the `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` to my custom listview layout `R.layout.list_layout`.

I was just experimenting because I'm having trouble understanding. 
Please help.

This is my Parser.class

```
public class Parser extends AsyncTask<Void,Integer,Integer> {



Context c;
ListView lv;

String data;


ArrayList<String> categories = new ArrayList<>();
ProgressDialog pd;

public Parser(Context c, String data, ListView lv) {
    this.c = c;
    this.data = data;
    this.lv = lv;

}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    pd = new ProgressDialog(c);
    pd.setTitle("Parsing Data");
    pd.setMessage("Please Wait...");
    pd.show();
}

@Override
protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {


    return this.parse();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Integer integer) {
    super.onPostExecute(integer);


    if(integer == 1)
    {
        //ADAPTER
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(c, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, categories);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if(position == 0){



                }


            }
        });

    }else
    {
        Toast.makeText(c,"Unable to Parse",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    pd.dismiss();
}

//PARSE RECEIVED DATA
private int parse(){


    try
    {

        //ADD THAT DATA TO JSON ARRAY FIRST
        JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(data);


        //CREATE JO OBJECT TO HOLD A SINGLE ITEM
        JSONObject jo = null;

        categories.clear();

        //LOOP THROUGH ARRAY
        for(int i =0 ; i<ja.length();i++)
        {
            jo = ja.getJSONObject(i);
            //RETRIEVE NAME
            name=jo.getString("item_name");
            price=jo.getString("item_price");

            //ADD TO ARRAY LIST
            categories.add(name + " " + price);





        }
        return 1;
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return 0;
}
```

}

Should it be better to not separate the classes or it will work the same?

Answer (score 0):

you should get response from web service and parse it (json object or json array) in one step

you can reach this in good way ,

**First** create class with json attribute name

in your case

```
Class JsonItem {
string item_name;
string item_price;

// create getter and setter 

}
```

Second use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) to parse your response

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

// 1. JSON to Java object, read it from a file.
JsonItem staff = gson.fromJson(YOUR_JSON_Here, JsonItem.class);
```

that is all

Comment: I don't think you have read my question sir. I can parse my data from my server. I just want to add a button to my listview.

Comment: yea cause you take wrong direction , parse class should carry reference to listview , and why you dont put the button in your mainactivity

Comment: I solved my own problem. How can I mark my question Answered?

Comment: you can answer your question , you will find blue button called Answer my question